# showing any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded by the standard norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let V be a real finite-dimensional vector space.
Let $$\|\cdot\|$$ be an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
Write $ x = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i e_i$ where $e_i$ is the standard basis. I am trying to show that $$\|x\| \leq C\|x\|_2$$ for some constant $C>0$. Does anyone have any advice?

This is for a bigger question, but I feel as though if I solve this I can solve the whole problem

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\|{\bf x}\| = \left\|\sum_i x_i {\bf e}_i\right\| \leq \sum_i \|x_i{\bf e}_i\| = \sum_i |x_i|\|{\bf e}_i\|.$$

Comment: yes I have gotten this far, sorry I should have posted my workings

Comment: It is never too late to add it in an edit :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a well-known result that all norms on a **finite** dimensional space are equivalent, of which yours is a special case.

Just note by the properties of a norm:

$$||x|| \le \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i| ||e_i||  \le  k \max_i\{|x_i| \} \max_i\{||e_i||\} \le k \max_i\{||e_i|| \} ||x||_2$$
Setting $C = k \max_i\{||e_i|| \}$ the claim is established.

Comment: sorry I don't follow - how did you get the max part from?

Comment: $|x_j| \le \max |x_i|$ and $||e_j|| \le \max ||e_i|| $ so the product is bounded by the product. So each summand is bounded by $\max |x_i| \max ||e_i||$ and you have $k$ terms.

Comment: that makes sense - but how did you involve $||x||_2$?

Comment: I bound $\max |x_i|$ by $||x||_2$ as $\sqrt{\sum x_i^2} \ge \sqrt{\max x_i^2}= \max |x_i| $.

Comment: thinki get it thanks

Answer (score 2):

By the triangle inequality, $\|x\| \le \sum_{k = 1}^n |x_i|\|e_i\|$, and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $\sum_{k = 1}^n |x_i|\|e_i\| \le C\|x\|_2$ with $C = \sqrt{\sum_{k = 1}^n \|e_i\|^2}$.

Comment: using this you used that $\sum ||x_i|| \leq \sum x_i^2$ could you explain how you got that

Comment: No, I didn't use that. Specifically, I used the fact that for any pair of vectors $v, w\in \Bbb R^n$, $v\cdot w \le \|v\|_2\|w\|_2$. Letting $v = (|x_1|,\ldots, |x_n|)$ and $w = (\|e_1\|,\ldots, \|e_n\|)$, we have $$\sum_{k = 1}^n |x_i|\|e_i\| = v\cdot w \le \|v\|_2\|w\|_2 = C\|v\|_2 = C\|x\|_2.$$

Comment: where are you getting that from? I am reading the wikipedia page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality under special cases

Comment: Right, the actual CS inequality is $|v\cdot w| \le \|v\|_2\|w\|_2$, from which it follows that $v \cdot w \le |v\cdot w| \le \|v\|_2\|w\|_2$.